# Reusing Retrofit method

Tags: android, android-activity, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a method that makes a call to my server using [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // ... activity methods here, removed for simplicity ...

    // Used to subscribe to a user given their userId
    public void subscribeToUser(int userId) {
        final ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.createService(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<BasicResponse> call = apiService.subscribe(userId);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<BasicResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<BasicResponse> call, Response<BasicResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<BasicResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I now need to use this same method (`subscribeToUser()`) in another activity, but it doesn't make sense to copy and paste the method into the other activity. Then I would just have the same code twice.

So can I put the method into one place and have it let the activities know whether or not the call succeeded or failed? How should I organize this?

Here is my `ApiClient.java` class:

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "http://www.website.com/api/";

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();

        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, final String authToken) {
        if (authToken != null) {
            httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request original = chain.request();

                    // Request customization: add request headers
                    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken)
                            .method(original.method(), original.body());

                    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            });
        }

        OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(client).build();

        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

And here is my `ApiInterface.java` class:

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("subscribe")
    Call<BasicResponse> subscribe(@Field("userId") Integer userId);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you try use `BaseActivity extend AppCompatActivity` contain method  `subscribeToUser` and after that `MainActivity` and other activity  extend BaseActivity.

Comment: @RoShanShan What if there comes a case that I need to use the `subscribeToUser()` method outside of an activity, like in an adapter?

Comment: I think you can use that method in Activity and send result to your adapter. Or you can send `context` to your adapter and use ((YouActivity)context).subscribeToUser().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, `createService(ApiInterface.class)` shouldn't be invoked multiple times. It's not necessary and slows down your application. You can try to create UserService with singleton pattern as below:

```
public class UserService {

private UserService userService;
final ApiInterface apiService;
//Contructor private to prevent init object from outside directly.
private UserService() {
    apiService = ApiClient.createService(ApiInterface.class);
}
//use this method when you need to use UserService 
public static UserService getInstance() {
    if(userService ==  null) {
        userService = new UserService();
    }
}

// Used to subscribe to a user given their userId
public void subscribeToUser(int userId, ServiceCallBack serviceCallBack) {
    final ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.createService(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<BasicResponse> call = apiService.subscribe(userId);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<BasicResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<BasicResponse> call, Response<BasicResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                serviceCallBack.successful(response);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<BasicResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            serviceCallBack.fail(t);
        }
    });
}
//this is callback interface, help you know whether success from outside.
interface ServiceCallBack {
     void successful(Response response);
    void fail(Throwable t);
}
}
```

How to use:

```
 UserService.getInstance(1, new ServiceCallBack(){

        @Override
        public void successful(Response response) {
            //process successful
        }

        @Override
        public void fail(Throwable t) {
            //process fail
        }
    });
```

Now you can put all methods relate to User api to UserService class to reuse.